Add embedded content to a Mural via the API
I use a lot of breakout rooms with Microsoft Teams in Mural and I want to be able to programmatically add links with meta data to a Mural canvas in the same way as manually adding it and then configuring the metadata.

Above is what it would look like in Mural once added...
I can already create the breakout room URL's from the Graph API, but I am struggling to even find any documentation on Mural ALP Ref that has anything to do with adding the embedded content that is described on Viewing embedded content in a mural.
I do not want to just add a URL to an existing object, but instead create the same embedded content that happens when I paste a URL.
I have tried searching for the terms embedded content and clickable thumbnails that is used in the user documentation, but I don't find any reference in the docs.
I have no idea where to even start!

If you can find a way to programmatically access and load items from your Mural Content Library, it could be a decent workaround. You would then need to create each breakout object one time, save it to your Content Library, and have them load from the library each time you need them.saved to content library in pairs. You could even save an entire "placemat" of breakouts in the Content Library to load them all at once.
saved area with 6 breakouts for 30 people.

the hyperlinks look suspicious. please explain what are those links containing
